# Excel/Sheets: Average only the input data in a range of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, average

I've got an annual budgeting spreadsheet in which each month is listed along with given categories of items. I'm trying to find my average monthly expenditure on any given category, but don't know the function for an average of only the months that have been input thus far. For example, I have data for Jan - June, but the standard "Average(Jan-Dec)" for instance creates an average with a denominator of 12, rather than a denominator of only as many months as have data at any given moment.

Is there a way to find an average with a changing denominator in this way?

Additionally, if there are certain months without data, is there a way to average only those cells with a numerical value?

Thank you!

Comment: The formula `=AVERAGEIF(range,"<>0")` should work. This function ignores blank cells.

Comment: Harrymc you are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula `=AVERAGEIF(range,"<>0")` should work to ignore zeroes.

This function ignores blank cells.